# Join two tables to one - Sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
id, mapid, life_type, lifeid, x_pos, y_pos, foothold, min_click_pos, max_click_pos, respawn_time, life.flags, script.script 
FROM 
map_life life 
LEFT JOIN 
scripts script 
ON 
script.objectid = life.lifeid 
AND 
script.script_type = 'npc' 
AND 
helper = 0 
LEFT JOIN 
npc_data n 
ON 
n.npcid = life.lifeid 
AND script.script_type = 'npc'
```

I'm trying to execute the following scripts. Basically, I'm showing all the rows from the table `map_life`, and also left joining column `script` from table `scripts` and column `storage_cost` from table `npc_data` **if** they `lifeid` column's value match `scripts`'s objectid and `npc_data`'s npcid.

However, it doesn't work properly. Why's that? I can't see the correct values for storage_cost.

Thanks

Comment: What database are you using, SQL Server or MySQL?  More importantly, I don't see `storage_cost` in the `select` list.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question please.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is missing the `[storage_cost]` column in the returned data set:

```
SELECT 
    life.[id], 
    life.[mapid], 
    life.[life_type], 
    life.[lifeid], 
    life.[x_pos], 
    life.[y_pos], 
    life.[foothold], 
    life.[min_click_pos], 
    life.[max_click_pos], 
    life.[respawn_time], 
    life.[flags], 
    script.[script], 
    npc.[storage_cost] 
FROM 
    [map_life] AS life 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [scripts] AS script 
        ON ( life.[lifeid] = script.[objectid] ) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [npc_data] AS npc 
        ON ( life.[lifeid] = npc.[npcid] )
WHERE 
    script.[script_type] = 'npc' 
    AND [helper] = 0
```

Also, it wasn't clear what table the `[helper]` column exists in. If the column is in the `[scripts]` table, then you could modify the query above by changing `[helper] = 0` in the WHERE Clause to instead be `script.[helper] = 0`.

<sub>**Added:**</sub>

Naturally, since you are using LEFT OUTER JOINs, the returned values for `script.[script]` and `npc.[storage_cost]` may be **NULL**.

I hope this helps.